# Android USB debuggin on Windows 8.1

Tags: android, windows, debugging

I am trying to run in Adobe Flash Professional CS6 and Eclipse my App on my telephone via USB debugging but it fails.

I have Windows 8.1. In Windows 7 I run my app on telephone without problem.

[image]

What do?

***OK!!! Gues I am find solution!!! Who have this problem go to http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=313678&st=15660#entry18627198 
Who's speak English sorry, learn Russian( учи русский бро =) )***

Answer (score 0):

Just install android tools for any model of android , if you have AVD manager download extras , after right click on youre device -> proprieties -> update drivers - > browse from youre PC  , then enter the path like C:\Users\youreUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

Comment: Update Driver -> (2nd option ) Browse my computer for  driver software -> let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer -> have disc - > enter C:\Users\youreUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver then next next yes yes (if more detailed description need)

Answer (score 0):

You should find your telephone in Devices of Eclipse IDE. e.g. my phone is detected in devices like below image.

 Install Xperia M2 Dual drivers.

[image]

**Editted** :: You have to ON USB Debugging from Developer Options.
[image]

Comment: But where I download this drivers if they don't? I instal all packages from programm Sony Pc Commpanion.

Comment: You have to ON USB debugging, see updated answer. Needed Internet connection, windows with download some drivers automatically.

Comment: I enabled USB debuggin on my devise but all the same